# Обязать наследников воспользоваться событием

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, в абстрактном классе описано событие.

Можно ли обязать наследников обязательно воспользоваться им?

Comment: Подпишите его на абстрактный метод.

Comment: воспользоваться в каком виде? Просто подписаться? или выбрасывать?

Comment: А толку? Ну они подпишутся, и ничего полезного делать не будут в обработчике?

Answer (score -1):

Насколько я понял, Вам просто нужно использовать интерфейс, содержащий это событие, для всех наследников.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?